# How to format date with hours, minutes and seconds when using jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to format a date with [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as to show hours, minutes and seconds?

This is my current mockup:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyy-dd-mm HH:MM:ss' }).val();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <title>snippet</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="datepicker">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

When I call `.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyy-dd-mm HH:MM:ss' })` the returned value is:

> 201313-07-03 HH:July:ss

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qv36W/1/).

Comment: The date picker only lets you select a date, not a time, so formatting hours, minutes, and seconds wouldn't be supported.  You can just append 00:00:00 yourself.

Comment: `var curTime = new Date()`.  You can use libraries like [moment](http://momentjs.com/) to format however you want.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd ");
```

For the time picker, you should add timepicker to Datepicker, and it would be formatted with one equivalent command.

**EDIT**

Use this one that extend jQuery UI Datepicker. You can pick up both date and time.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: i try more to find out an answer about this but finally i found your answer in last.i like to suggest you that your answer return object of datepicker so i modify in my coding like this.Thank you ...                                                                                                                                                                                       $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy").val();

Comment: What about date and time together? Doesn't seem like it allows this format: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` in the library link you provided.

Answer (score 49):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/5qkt8e06/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext) {
            var d = new Date(); // for now

            var h = d.getHours();
            h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h ;

            var m = d.getMinutes();
            m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m ;

            var s = d.getSeconds();
            s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s ;

            datetext = datetext + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: great solution, but it doesn't add leading zeros. 

You can add them like this: `('0'+d.getHours()).slice(-2)`
And it is better to apply new value to `$(this)` instead of `$('#datepicker')`. It may be helpful if you have more than one elements in selector, like `$('.datepicker').datepicker(...)`

Comment: useful, but it disables 'change' events. I've added `$(this).trigger('change')` at the end of `onSelect`

Answer (score 36):

Using jQuery UI in combination with the excellent datetimepicker plugin from http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

You can specify the **dateFormat** and **timeFormat**

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    timeFormat:  "hh:mm:ss"
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Or, using datetimepicker plugin.

Ref: [DateTimePicker AM/PM Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974697/datetimepicker-am-pm-dropdown/20794434#20794434)

Ref: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1):

If don't like to add time picker, we can use just javascript for time part.

```
  var dateObj=new Date();
  var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', dateObj);
  var time  = dateObj.getHours()+":"+dateObj.getMinutes()+":"+dateObj.getSeconds(); 

  console.log(date," ",time);
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this code

```
<input class="form-control input-small hasDatepicker" id="datepicker6" name="expire_date" type="text" value="2018-03-17 00:00:00">

<script src="/assets/js/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#datepicker6").datepicker({
                isRTL: true,
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd 23:59:59",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true

            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-d-m ' }).val();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <title>snippet</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="datepicker">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting Started**
Install from npm:

**npm install imask
And import or require:**

import IMask from 'imask';

**or use CDN:**

```
var dateMask = IMask(element, {
  mask: Date,  // enable date mask

  // other options are optional
  pattern: 'Y-`m-`d',  // Pattern mask with defined blocks, default is 'd{.}`m{.}`Y'
  // you can provide your own blocks definitions, default blocks for date mask are:
  blocks: {
    d: {
      mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
      from: 1,
      to: 31,
      maxLength: 2,
    },
    m: {
      mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
      from: 1,
      to: 12,
      maxLength: 2,
    },
    Y: {
      mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
      from: 1900,
      to: 9999,
    }
  },
  // define date -> str convertion
  format: function (date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
  },
  // define str -> date convertion
  parse: function (str) {
    var yearMonthDay = str.split('-');
    return new Date(yearMonthDay[0], yearMonthDay[1] - 1, yearMonthDay[2]);
  },

  // optional interval options
  min: new Date(2000, 0, 1),  // defaults to `1900-01-01`
  max: new Date(2020, 0, 1),  // defaults to `9999-01-01`

  autofix: true,  // defaults to `false`

  // also Pattern options can be set
  lazy: false,

  // and other common options
  overwrite: true  // defaults to `false`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
        $('#myelement').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            timeFormat:  "hh:mm:ss"
        });
```