# Issue with DateTime Property

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my property in my model:

```
[Display(Name = "Date / Time:")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DayTime { get; set; }
```

For my application it is necessary to include the time.

Here is my *.cshtml*

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DayTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DayTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DayTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using jQuery Datepicker.

When the user initially goes to the *Create* page, I have it setup so that it will automatically have today's date and current time already in the `EditorFor` as so:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        DailySummary daily = new DailySummary();
        daily.DayTime = DateTime.Now;

        return View(daily);
    }
```

Now that all works fine, until I want to change the date and time... I am able to change the Date portion but I am unable to add the `HH:mm` part of the DateTime... like the `EditorFor` isn't allowing me to space from the Date portion to enter the time.

How do I fix this so that I can enter the time portion along with the date?

Comment: This requires an extension of jQuery UI. I think it doesn't have this functionality by default. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438857/format-date-with-hours-minutes-and-seconds-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: @JDupont I just tried those solutions. and still experiencing same issue

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I found [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I went into *Nuget* and downloaded the `.CSS` version of `Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS`.

After referencing the newly downloaded files in my `_Layout` View I followed the simple instructions in the link given above, and it works like a charm.