# How add custom string mate time to date-picker result in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I'm new to date-picker concept. I have a date picker which return a selected date to a input field [type="text"]. Now I want to add time(Which is stored as a string in a variable) to that date and place in that input field.

Code here:

```
html
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <input type="text" class="dateselect" required="required"/>
    <span>Date</span>
  </label>  
</div>

js
-----------------------------------------------------
var time = "1:30PM";

$('.dateselect').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: new Date(),
    autoclose: true,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    // startDate: '-3d'

});
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

### Output:

[output with given suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCyaL.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format date with hours, minutes and seconds when using jQuery UI Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438857/how-to-format-date-with-hours-minutes-and-seconds-when-using-jquery-ui-datepick)

Comment: No, My issue is bit different.

Comment: how is it different?

`For the time picker, you should add timepicker to Datepicker, and it would be formatted with one equivalent command.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simulated example of how to do what you ask.

```js
let time = " 1:30PM";
let inputDate = $('.dateselect').val();
let inputDateTime = inputDate + time;
$('.dateselect').val(inputDateTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <input type="text" class="dateselect" required="required" value="02/22/2020"/>
    <span>Date</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your right. I already tried that part. But it is not displaying the time in the input field. And when I try to access that element from javascript and printing to console it showing date along with time.

Comment: Did you run the snippet? It appears to do exactly what you describe in your question. What am I missing?

Comment: In your example it working perfectly. My end also working fine. but not displaying in browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dateselect").datetimepicker('destroy');
```

this line is used to display the updated value on browser.